# Python: Netcat function doen't work

Tags: python

When I use this command on Linux, it works:

```
echo "test.bash.stats 44 1459116000" | nc myhostname.com 2003
```

But now, I try to implement this command in a Python script.

Method 1: Use `os.system("")`

```
# this works
os.system("echo 'test.bash.stats 14 1459116000' | nc myhostname.com 2003")

#It does not work because there are a problem with quote
data['time_timestamp'] = 1459116000
os.system("echo 'test.bash.stats 14 "data['time_timestamp']"' | nc myhostname.com 2003")
```

Method 2: Use socket

```
import socket

def netcat(hostname, port, content):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((hostname, port))
    s.sendall(content)
    s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
    while 1:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if data == "":
            break
        print "Received:", repr(data)
    print "Connection closed."
    s.close()

netcat("myhostname.com", 2003, "test.bash.stats 14 1459116000")
```

I don't get an error, but I don't receive data.

Comment: Don't you need a `+` to concatenate a string?

     `os.system("echo 'test.bash.stats 14 " + str(data['time_timestamp']) + " '| nc myhostname.com 2003")`

That should do it. I tested it and in my case python only complained about "data" after I imported os

Comment: @querist: He would need to convert it to a string.  He mentions that it is an integer...

Comment: True, @zondo. str to the rescue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try concatenating the string like this

```
os.system("echo 'test.bash.stats 14 " + str(data['time_timestamp']) + " '| nc myhostname.com 2003")
```

or this

```
os.system("echo 'test.bash.stats 14 %d '| nc myhostname.com 2003" % data['time_timestamp'])
```